# Need to provide an "in-page" search for a single list querying only 2 columns in a multi-column list

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-search-webparts

I have PnP Modern Search installed and so far have found that this is not enough. When I configure searches, I get results from all fields in the entire list and resulting in results from all columns.

This presents a problem when I search for a code of name "AS".  This code is in the two fields I need, but it is also in many of the more descriptive text fields.

I want to only search the two fields where this code would be queried from and skip the longer text based description fields.

Do I need to look into Managed Result Sources to accomplish this?  Not quite sure what direction to take to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on my own for this problem.  By default it appears that the title field has both a crawled property and a managed property, but the other columns only have crawled properties.

I had to create new managed properties and map them to the crawled properties and then use the following code in my PnP Search Web Part to make it happen.

```
Title:({searchTerms}) OR TestDirectoryTestName:({searchTerms}) OR TestDirectorySynonyms:({searchTerms}){ABCDEFG-2D24-4EE7-ABCDE-98XYZ1236A6C}
```